# Trouble translating SQL query to Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have a search page that narrows down the list of a specific class, and I want an OR condition that can grab two different conditions and add the together, for example, I have classes

model/party.rb

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :invitations
end
```

mode/invitation.rb

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :party
end
```

invitation has a status attribute, which will be "decline", "accept", or "unanswered"

What I want to do is grab all the parties that do not have any invitations, or any that have all of the invitations "unanswered".

I currently do

```
  scope :not_confirmed, lambda { find_by_sql( "SELECT * FROM `parties` INNER JOIN `invitations` ON `invitations`.`party_id` = `parties`.`id` WHERE (invitations.status = 'unanswered') OR (parties.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(party_id) FROM invitations))" ) }
```

which works, but since it does not lazy load I can't add them in a facet like query.

I did something like

```
no_invitations.or(no_one_has_answered)
```

but it did not work.

I especially do not get the concept of using OR on AREL, could someone please help out?

**edited:**

For a very ugly yet functional work around until I get this down, here is what I have done

party.rb

```
  scope :not_confirmed, lambda { joins(:invitations).where( "invitations.status NOT IN (?)", ["accepted", "declined" ] ) }
  scope :with_no_invitations, lambda { includes(:invitaions).where( :invitations => { :party_id => nil } ) }
```

search_controller.rb

```
@parties = Party.all_the_shared_queries
@parties = ( @parties.not_confirmed + @parties.with_no_invitations).uniq
```

Comment: can you share your scopes `no_invitations` and `no_one_has_answered`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, from the question tags, I have assumed that you are using Rails3 (had it been Rails4, there were more easy ways of doing things :))

For your requirement above (**ie grab all the parties that do not have any invitations, or any that have all of the invitations "unanswered")**, here is a way of doing it (using scope :unattended):

Party Model:

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitations
  scope :invitations_answered, -> { joins(:invitations).merge(Invitation.answered) }
  scope :unattended, -> { where(arel_table[:id].not_in invitations_answered.pluck(:id)) }
end
```

Invitation Model:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :party
  scope :answered, -> { where(status: ["decline", "accept"])}
end
```

In Rails 4, you can use `where.not` and simplify it further like this:

Party Model:

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitations
  scope :invitations_answered, -> { joins(:invitations).merge(Invitation.answered) }
  scope :unattended, -> { where.not(id: invitations_answered.pluck(:id)) }
end
```

Invitation Model:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :party
  scope :answered, -> { where.not(status: 'unanswered') }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for the sake of future reference, could you add how it could be done in Rails4. updating to it is totaly doable.

Comment: Thankyou, that did the trick! did not think about flipping the condition around to get what I need, much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The query:

```
  scope :not_confirmed, lambda { find_by_sql( "SELECT * FROM `parties` INNER JOIN `invitations` ON `invitations`.`party_id` = `parties`.`id` WHERE (invitations.status = 'unanswered') OR (parties.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(party_id) FROM invitations))" ) }
```

can be converted to [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) with some transformation using boolean algebra too. But since it is only **theoretical** conversion, you have to verify it manually. So:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :party

   scope :non_answered, -> { where(arel_table[:status].not_eq('unanswered')) }
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :invitations

   scope :not_confirmed, -> { not.join(:invitaions).merge(Invitation.non_answered)) }
end
```

Please test it and comment here.

Comment: Wouldn't this not be able to find the parties without invitations? or am I miss-understanding the whole thing?

Comment: @saifis as far as I understood the task , you have to select all unanswered records plus record without an invitation , am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And from what I can understand, wouldn't the above check all invitaions that are not "unaswered" only? I'm not sure what you mean by converting the sql into areal with boolean algebra.

Comment: @Saifis however you have accepted the answer below, I'll answer you. well something like this: `SELECT... WHERE NOT (<clause>)`. But I'll think again

Comment: @Saifis could you try `#not` without args?

Comment: Thank you, that will work, the most important factor to solve my problem was to use the not to reverse the condition, thank you for response!